# Cross Posting on Related Forums

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, unanswered-questions

As StackExchange has such a diverse network of technology sites, is it permissible to post a question to a second forum if they don't get any answers after a day or other extended period of time?

In particular, I posted a question on StackOverflow about ZenCart which hasn't gotten any responses after two days, so I'm not sure if the question should be moved and/or reposed to the Webmasters forum or Web Apps forum.

The original question in mind is located at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902039/zen-cart-itemized-shipping-totals

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Comment: FYI Web Apps is generally for *hosted* applications, [not](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) stuff you'd install on your own server, like Zencart. If you flag the question to be moved, this site would be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks very much for that clarification. I had a feeling the Web Apps forum was for SAAS and other hosted platforms but I wasn't exactly sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you shouldn't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que/64073#64073) -- that is, post the exact same question on multiple sites. If you rephrase the question to be specifically about each site's domain, that's fine. If you'd rather just move a question from one site to another, flag it for mod attention and ask them to migrate it

Comment: This is exactly what you want to do. If you create multiple copies of the exact same question and one of your questions is moved to another site then you question could be duplicated on that site and things can become a bit messy.  It is best to flag a mod to move it or to reword the question to be within the second sites domain.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the answers. That was my exact thinking but I wanted to double check.